# Correct Usage Of System.Threading.Timer

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, timer

I stumbled across some code similar to below:

```
private void SomeCallBack(object state)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_timer == null)
                    return;

                _timer.Dispose();
                // do some work here
            }
            catch
            {
                // handle exception
            }
            finally
            {
                _timer = new Timer(SomeCallBack, state, 100, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't understand the purpose of recreating the timer every time the callback is executed. I think what the code is trying to achieve is that only one thread can perform the work at a time. But wouldn't the lock be sufficient?

Also, according to msdn,

> Note that callbacks can occur after the Dispose() method overload has been called

Is there any benefits of doing this?
If so, do the benefits justify the overheads in disposing and creating the timer?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the code wants a nearly periodic timer (not exactly periodic because of the jitter introduced by the processing between the expiration of the timer and creation of the new timer). Disposing and recreating the timer is indeed an unnecessary overhead. The `Change` method would be better.

The check for null is also curious; somewhere else there would have to be code that sets `_timer` null for it to have any effect.

Comment: The timer is set to null in the function to stop the timer. If you just set the interval to 100 wouldn't that achieve the same thing? You don't even need to use `Change()`. The state is not modified in the function so the purpose of recreating the timer is not to pass in new parameters for the actual work.

Comment: This answer is correct. The code is creating a one-shot timer. The effect is that there will be a 100 ms delay between when one callback ends and the next starts. But since the period is set to `Timeout.Infinite`, the timer won't fire again. The same effect could be achieved by calling `_timer.Change(100, Timeout.Infinite)`, except that it wouldn't handle the case of the timer being `null`. In the existing code, if the timer is null, there is no processing, but a new timer is created in the `finally`.

Comment: Also, the use of a lock here is curious. Unless there are multiple timers using this callback, there's no way it will be called by multiple threads concurrently. The timer is a one-shot, making re-entrant calls impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for recreating the timer would be for the scenario where the code in the timer callback takes longer to execute than the timer period. In this case multiple instances of the callback would be running at the same time.